# Exclude all values in a column on a different sheet from a Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

So I have the following query:

```
=QUERY('sheet - Users'!A1:S, "Select A,B,C,F,G,O,Q,S where Q >= 44223 and not lower(O) matches '.*archived.*|.*archived' and not lower(C) matches '.*admin.*|.*admin' and not UPPER(C) matches '.*SMB.*' and not C matches '.*Shared Mailbox.*' and S >=90",1)
```

This works perfectly fine (as convoluted as it is), however, I have a list of exceptions that I need to remove from the results (the list could change, so ideally this needs to be dynamic and not hard coded).

I did some digging around and found this [example query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125305):

```
=query(C2:C8,"select C where C<>'"&JOIN("' and C<>'",D2:D10)&"'"&""
```

But that doesn't seem to be working for me when I try to incorporate it into my query.

The data I need to exclude is on a sheet called: Exclusion List
And is in cells C2:C

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: I tried to answer from the point of view that you want to exclude values from a range on another sheet into the query. But I cannot test the complete query without a copy of the sheet. If my answer still not works on your end, please post your complete query that you tried and share a copy of the sheet.

Comment: there is no limit when it comes to queries. share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

You can modify the exclusion list to reference `C2:C` from another sheet, like this:

```
=query(C2:C8,"select C where C<>'"&JOIN("' and C<>'",'Exclusion List'!C2:C)&"'"&""
```

**Sample Query and Exclusion Sheet:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I think I have solved my issue. It's purely because of the amount of data.
I think I'm hitting a limit for the join. As it's coming up with an error saying: 

    "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "ambrosio "" at line 1, column 5328. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "and" ... "or" ..."

And I know that's part of one of the email addresses. I'm now stumped!

Comment: In that case it is possible that your data format is different, we would be able to help you more if you post this as another question and share a copy of your sheet. Also, if you are satisfied with the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers